# iPhone: Save image to a specific photo album

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

The application I am working on manipulates an image for a user, and after the user is done, they can save that photo.  I have no problem capturing the screen and saving it (as I want some of the labels saved with the image) but this call:

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self getScreenAsImage] , nil, nil, nil);

only appears to allow me to save to the 'Saved Photos' album.  Ideally I would like to create an album named after the application I am working on and save it there so that they are all stored together (for example like the Hawaii or graduation day albums on the simulator).  It would also be nice then to launch the image picker in that specific album.  Anyone know how to do this?  Most important part is to be able to save it in an album, being able to launch the picker in that album is of secondary importance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Apple has not exposed an SDK to allow for this.  After a review the UIKit function reference, My fear seems confirmed.

Comment: Thanks Brad, that is basically what I was figuring after extensive googling, so it is good to have that confirmed.

Comment: Has there been any change on this behavior or is it still forbidden?

Comment: Brad Smith, it's hard to google nowadays because there is always someone like you who don't even bother to answer it and make ppl thank you are pro or something. I googled this question and came here, and then asked to google again, LOL

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it, Apple just hasn't made it simple.

There is a custom category that adds the functionality to ALAssetsLibrary.

**Git** repo for the category can be found [here](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum)

and if you are using Cocoapods you can get it with

```
pod 'ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum'
```

You will need to instantiate a ALAssetsLibrary object and call the method below

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image
      toAlbum:(NSString *)albumName
   completion:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completion
      failure:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failure
```

Something like below

Import:

```
#import "ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h" //Source Included (Git)
```

or

```
#import <ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum.h> //Cocoapods
```

Call:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLib saveImage:imageToSave
                      toAlbum:@"AlbumName"
                   completion:completionBlock
                      failure:failureBlock];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**ALAssetsLibrary**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for doing this:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"Midhun" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
```

Check this tutorial also: [**Custom Photo Album**](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)